# Find Currency/Amount Within $1.00

Tags: mysql, t-sql, decimal, currency, between

How would I query for an Amount Column that is within 1.00 of the actual Amount?

For instance, if AmountPaid = 7.75, I would like to return all results where Amount between 6.75 - 8.75.

I know I am overlooking something simple, but as of now, I have the following code...

```
Where (vc.AmountPaid >= med.Payment - 1.00 or vc.amountpaid <= med.Payment + 1.00)
```

Comment: Where (vc.AmountPaid between med.Payment - 1.00 and med.Payment + 1.00)

Answer (score 1):

```
Where (vc.AmountPaid between med.Payment - 1.00 and med.Payment + 1.00)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace OR keyword with AND.

something like this

```
Where (vc.AmountPaid >= med.Payment - 1.00 AND vc.amountpaid <= med.Payment + 1.00)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overlooking the [ABS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql) function.

The most simple way to get what you are looking for would be:

```
where abs(AmountPaid-payment) <= 1
```

ABS is good when I am dealing with numerical differences. the difference between 10 and 12, and 12 and 10 is the same: 2. Note this example (that you can just copy/paste into SSMS and run):

```
declare @yourdata table (AmountPaid money, Payment money);
insert @yourdata values (50.00, 49.12),(100, 100.91),(25,1000),(10,20);

select AmountPaid, Payment, diff = abs(AmountPaid-payment)
from @yourdata
where abs(AmountPaid-payment) <= 1;
```

**returns**

```
AmountPaid            Payment               diff
--------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
50.00                 49.12                 0.88
100.00                100.91                0.91
```

Comment: While that is correct on the surface, by using the ABS function in that manner you have made the query non-sargable. Here's a good article here (https://blog.bertwagner.com/how-to-search-and-destroy-non-sargable-queries-on-your-server-ff9f57c7268e).

Comment: @Katherine Elizabeth Lightsey - What I posted isn't just "correct on the surface" - it is correct to the core. Lack of SARGability should not constitute a down-vote as this was a how-to question which led to a good learning opportunity. Furthermore - my solution could be turned into an indexed view and therefore SARGability is no longer an issue.